Why can't I change the color of objects created with the Spray tool
After using the spray tool to create objects, I am unable to change the fill/stroke of them.
Sprayed objects will not react to changes in fill or stroke.

Objects created with the spray tool are clones. Those clones need to be split up before altering the fill or stroke.
Edit -> Clone -> Unlink Clone (Shift-Alt-D)

By default, the spray tool in Inkscape sprays clones of the shapes you have selected.  So, you can't change the colour of the clones themselves. You could however change the colour of the clone sources, and all the clones will update automatically.
However, you can instead change the settings in the controls bar along the top to use "Spray Copies" instead of clones. Then after you have sprayed them, you can select them individually and change the stroke or fill.
Here's the setting, and in action.



My question was specifically how to alter the colors after having sprayed them, but having your answer here is great for a more complete picture of how to avoid ending up in the situation if you know ahead you want to alter them individually.
